# how to set pause between events fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I wonder if there is any possibility to make a pause between events, lets say, 30 minutes, in fullcalendar. I've searched for such possible configuration but didn't find anything.

My question is if there is any possibility to set those "spaces" between(so it would only be possible for user to select another event after or before 30 minutes) in config or should it be done programmatically?

Comment: are you saying that you want to enforce a 30-minute gap between each event? Basically I think you would have to handle the "select" callback (and the drop/resize ones if you allow moving/editing), and compare the event to all the other events currently displayed, and check whether the start time is within 30 mins of the end time (or vice versa, if the new event is earlier than the existing one). Let me know if you'd like me to elaborate.

Comment: @ADyson Yes. Exactly. I'm not really good in fc, just recently started to learn it, tried to implement a script that would not let user to select event time closer than 30 minutes to each event but it doesn't work so far

Comment: well please edit your question to share that script and then maybe I can help improve it. Also please explain precisely how/where it doesn't work.

Comment: @ADyson ok I'll edit question when I get back to my main computer